# How to fake ASP.NET MVC UrlHelper with FakeitEasy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mstest, fakeiteasy

This is the code of my controller :

```
private readonly ILMS_Service lms_client;
private UrlHelper urlHelper;

public PackagesController(ILMS_Service client, UrlHelper _urlHelper)
{
    lms_client = client;
    urlHelper = _urlHelper;
}

public PackagesController()
{
    lms_client = new LMS_ServiceClient();
    urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPackageDetails(
    int packageID,
    string package_name,
    int unit_type,
    int product_id,
    int unit_count,
    string description
    )
{
    lms_client.EditPackageDetails(
        packageID,
        package_name,
        unit_type,
        product_id,
        unit_count,
        description);
        
    var url = urlHelper.Action("PackagesList", "Packages");

    return Json(new
    {
        statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        redirectURL = url
    });
}
```

The `urlBuilder.Action("PackagesList", "Packages");` returns null during the test run. I am trying to fake the `UrlHelper` class with a fake return value by assigning it to the controller but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the current implementation of my test:

```
private readonly PackagesController _controller_Packages;
private readonly ILMS_Service _lms_service;

private readonly HttpContextBase httpContext;
private readonly HttpResponseBase httpResponse;
private readonly HttpSessionStateBase httpSession;
private readonly UrlHelper urlBuilder;

public Packages_UnitTest()
{
    // Mock WCF
    _lms_service = A.Fake<ILMS_Service>();

    // Fake session
    httpContext = A.Fake<HttpContextBase>();
    httpResponse = A.Fake<HttpResponseBase>();
    httpSession = A.Fake<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    urlBuilder = A.Fake<UrlHelper>();
    
    //SUTs
    _controller_Packages = new PackagesController(_lms_service, urlHelper);

    A.CallTo(() => httpContext.Response).Returns(httpResponse);
    A.CallTo(() => httpContext.Session).Returns(httpSession);
}

[TestMethod]
public void should_EditPackageDetails()
{
    // Arrange
    int packageID = 1;
    string package_name = "Test package";
    int unit_type = 1;
    int product_id = 1;
    int unit_count = 10;
    string description = "Sample test description";

    int expected_statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    string expected_page_destination = "/Packages/PackagesList";

    var context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), _controller_Packages);
    _controller_Packages.ControllerContext = context;

    A.CallTo(() => urlBuilder.Action("PackagesList", "Packages"))
        .Returns("/Packages/PackagesList");

    // Act
    _ = A.CallTo(() => _lms_service.EditPackageDetails(
        A<int>.Ignored,
        A<string>.Ignored,
        A<int>.Ignored,
        A<int>.Ignored,
        A<int>.Ignored,
        A<string>.Ignored
        ));

    var _editPackage = _controller_Packages.EditPackageDetails(
        packageID,
        package_name,
        unit_type,
        product_id,
        unit_count,
        description
        ) as JsonResult;

    dynamic result = _editPackage.Data;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected_statusCode, result.statusCode);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected_page_destination, result.redirectURL);
}
```

With this test, it is still returning null, not `"/Packages/PackagesList"`. How can I fake `UrlHelper` with it returning `"/Packages/PackagesList"` as the value with FakeitEasy? Any help would be appreciated. I have an ASP.NET MVC 4, MSTest, and FakeitEasy mocking framework. Thanks!

Comment: Aside: you half-configure `_lms_service.EditPackageDetails`. It's not the cause of your problem, but I do not think this does anything, and the call distracts from the useful code in the test.

Comment: @BlairConrad but my intention is to run the external service just to make the controller method run throughout the test. The ```_lms_service.EditPackageDetails``` returns void anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up injecting the UrlHelper to the constructor of the SUT and added an `if` statement to check if the `urlBuilder` has been already instantiated. Once the `.Action()` is called, it will then return the faked path I defined as you can see on the `A.CallTo()` part of my test.

Note that the SUT and test below is just an excerpt of my full code to clear out distractions.

**SUT**

```
private UrlHelper urlHelper;

public PackagesController(UrlHelper _urlHelper)
{
    urlHelper = _urlHelper;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPackageDetails(
    int packageID,
    string package_name,
    int unit_type,
    int product_id,
    int unit_count,
    string description
    )
{
    lms_client.EditPackageDetails(
        packageID,
        package_name,
        unit_type,
        product_id,
        unit_count,
        description);

    if(urlHelper == null)
        urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);

    var url = urlHelper.Action("PackagesList", "Packages");

    return Json(new
    {
        statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        redirectURL = url
    });
}
```

**Test**

```
private readonly PackagesController _controller_Packages;
private readonly ILMS_Service _lms_service;

private readonly UrlHelper urlHelper;

public Packages_UnitTest()
{
    // Mock WCF
    _lms_service = A.Fake<ILMS_Service>();

    // Fakes
    urlHelper = A.Fake<UrlHelper>();

    // SUTs
    _controller_Packages = new PackagesController(_lms_service, urlHelper);
}

[TestMethod]
public void should_EditPackageDetails()
{
    // Arrange
    int packageID = 1;
    string package_name = "Test package";
    int unit_type = 1;
    int product_id = 1;
    int unit_count = 10;
    string description = "Sample test description";

    int expected_statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    string expected_page_destination = "/Packages/PackagesList";

    A.CallTo(() => urlHelper.Action("PackagesList", "Packages"))
        .Returns("/Packages/PackagesList");

    // Act
    _ = A.CallTo(() => _lms_service.EditPackageDetails(
        A<int>.Ignored,
        A<string>.Ignored,
        A<int>.Ignored,
        A<int>.Ignored,
        A<int>.Ignored,
        A<string>.Ignored
        ));

    var _editPackage = _controller_Packages.EditPackageDetails(
        packageID,
        package_name,
        unit_type,
        product_id,
        unit_count,
        description
        ) as JsonResult;

    dynamic result = _editPackage.Data;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected_statusCode, result.statusCode);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected_page_destination, result.redirectURL);
}
```

The `if` statement on my method seems to be a hacky way to fake UrlHelper. It wasn't my intention to add the conditional statement there though so this is not the most elegant way of doing this. If there's a better implementation, please let me know. Any additional information always helps!

Answer (score 0):

The fake `UrlHelper` looks fine to me, but you're not using it inside `EditPackageDetails`. You're using a new `UrlHelper` that you construct:

```cs
var urlBuilder = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
```

use `_controller_Packages.Url` instead.

And a hint for the future: it can often be helpful to debug your tests. Examine the values that you're using that you think might be Fakes, to see if they really are.

Comment: I tried passing ```_controller_Packages.Url = urlBuilder``` but it still returns null; it doesn't seem to work. I made an attempt by injecting ```UrlHelper``` to the constructor and updated my code on my question. It works through DI, the ```UrlHelper``` is faked and passes the test but when I run the app through IIS Express, the ```Request.RequestContext``` throws an **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** on the constructor. It seems it only works only the method. If I use ```_controller_Packages.Url```, what is the correct implementation?